# How to prevent cell editing after pushing header section item?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtgui

When I push horizontal header section item in `QTableWidget` the upper cell in this column becomes ready to be edited.
How can I prevent it?

[image: QTableWidget]

[image]

Comment: By default, when a column's header is clicked, the whole column is selected. Maybe it is something that has to do with your code/properties you have set on the `QTableWidget`. Please provide all the properties you have changed in your `QTableWidget` and/or the relevant part of code ( preferably in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ).

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], if you do not do it for me this question should be closed as it falls on the off-topic: **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.**

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you looking for? Should a column be selected when you click on a header? Should editing automatically start when you select a cell? Please include all relevant information in your question (as text), instead of adding a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the interference of

- selecting a column when clicking on the column header and
- immediately start editing when an item is selected ([`editTriggers > CurrentChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum))

So, basically, you should disable one or both behaviours.

- To disable selecting a column when its header is clicked, you can have a look at the question *[Disable selecting row or column by clicking the header in QTableWidget](/q/5421947)* containing many alternative solutions.
- Or do not immediately start editing by disabling `CurrentChanged`.

Comment: `disconnect(horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionPressed(int)),this, SLOT(selectColumn(int)));` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qtablewidget.html) documentation i found a way to fix your problem. You have to edit the every single [vertical header item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qtablewidget.html#verticalHeaderItem) and modify their [flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qtablewidgetitem.html#setFlags) to be not editable.

```
const int size = ui->tableWidget->columnCount();
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
     QTableWidgetItem * item = ui->tableWidget->verticalHeaderItem(i);
     item->setFlags(...every single flag you want);
}
```

You have a list of the available flags in this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum).

Comment: Its working fine for me: QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(); item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);

Comment: Updated. - - - -